# Zend Framework - MSSQL cannot receive UTF-8 chars

Tags: php, sql-server, database, zend-framework, character-encoding

I have a problem with Zend Framework not receiving UTF-8 characters from database tables.

I am connecting to MS SQL server with Zend and receiving notes from db. When they contains e.g. `'š'`

or `'č'` (small latin c or s with carbon) (chars that are not in ASCII), they are automatically

converted do they non-carbon versions 'c' or 's'.

Since they are not coming into my php like that, i cannot use php functions like utf8_encode,

utf8_decode, iconv, mb_convert_encoding etc.. because 'č' is yet 'c'. Also, converting the code

file into any charset is useless. Writen text and text from files is encoded ok.

In my application.ini:

```
resources.view.charset = utf-8
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"

resources.db.params.charset = "UTF8"
```

there's a string in db with value `'čaďa'`

after reading and echoing to the screen:

```
echo $this->note // cada
echo utf8_decode($this->note) // cada
echo mb_convert_encoding($this->note, 'UTF-8') // cada
```

Collation of database: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Any help?

Comment: Try changing collation to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` and see what happens (change AS to AI).

Comment: Can't modify the database :-)